# z-index não funciona com anuncio google adsense

Tags: javascript, css

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte.

Tenho um menu no top com position fixed e um z-index de 99999. Coloquei esse anuncio mas o problema q estou tendo é quando eu vou pra baixo e a chego na propaganda. A propaganda fica na frente do meu menu. Já tentei usar position menor que o do meu menu mas de nada adiantou.

IMG Do problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que esse anuncio fique abaixo do meu menu.

Script do anuncio :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5653567333761325";
                google_ad_slot = "4495238327";
                google_ad_width = 336;
                google_ad_height = 280;
            </script>
            <!-- Anuncio_aside -->
            <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
            </script>
```

Comment: quase certeza que o limite de 9s são  de 5 a 7. e sim já tentei.

Comment: Pode mostrar o link do site?

Comment: Vc está colocando o anúncio em uma div?

Comment: Tente usar o console do navegador (F12 para Chrome e Firefox) pra fazer a alteração direto no elemento e ter certeza se funciona ou não.

Comment: olá, o anúncio do google após ser exibido no navegador deve estar em uma DIV e com certeza contem um ID ou uma CLASSE CSS diferente que você possa identificar com jquery, dessa forma você localiza o objeto via jquery e insere uma classe contendo z-index 1 para ficar abaixo do conteúdo do seu site/sistema.

Comment: Consegui, usando o inspecionar elemento. achei o id e coloquei um z-index no css.